# Choose postback URL of according to situation

Tags: asp.net

I control if a user exist in database. If it dont exist, I want to stay login page. If it  exist, I want to go Default.aspx page.

```
protected void BtnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(condition is okey)
    { 
        // go default.aspx
    } 
     else
    { 
        //stay this page
    }
}
```

What can I write on comment lines to achive this? 
Thanks!

Comment: since your redirect condition is centered around authentication it is worth asking if you have looked into the asp.net membership structure and the login controls.  It's pretty straight forward to setup and it will handle keeping the user on the login page and taking them to a default location on success.  if this fits your needs you end up with cleaner and more reliable code since your are not rolling your own.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you just want to do a redirect:

```
protected void BtnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(myCondition)
    { 
        Response.Redirect("/default.aspx");
    } 
    else
    { 
        //stay this page
    }
}
```

If you want to retain the POST data, you can use `Server.Transfer` instead (note: based on your edits, it *doesn't* sound like this is what you need - I think you just need `Response.Redirect`):

```
Server.Transfer("/default.aspx");
```

Note that transferring the handler of the POST like this will *not* cause a browser redirect and therefore will *not* change the browser URL.

If you need to actually POST to a different URL and have the browser update, you'll need to post directly to that URL using a cross-page postback (using the `action` attribute on the form element), validate on that page and then redirect back to the original page if validation fails.